How can I fill the voids between the pebbles in a polished stone aggregate kitchen countertop?
My brother is renting a house with an L-shaped kitchen countertop that appears to be made of lots of little (1/4" and smaller) stones held together by . a very hard glass-type binder and polished to a mirror finish. The countertop was probably installed by the tract builder about 30 years ago. The problem is the countertop surface has a gazillion small voids between the small stones. The voids are distributed across the whole countertop and appear to be part of the original manufacture rather than the result of surface deterioration. The voids trap grunge and small food particles, making it impossible to keep the counters clean. I'm imagining a resurfacing treatment that would spread a coating over the countertop and then polishing it.  Does such a treatment exist?

your problem will be having anything stick to the contaminated area (food etc), the best solution would be to overlay a tempered glass plate, the disadvantage ben you can not use hammer, the advantage will be you do not have to polish it

Given the place is a rental, cutting boards on top of the counter and under any food would be the correct option until the landlord has approved of you carrying out your scheme. "Helpful" unapproved modifications to rentals can prove very expensive, if you manage to make the counters worse, or if the landlord simply doesn't want the counters modified by nonprofessionals.

If you use a uv resin, you should be able to get a glass finish by simply waiting a little while before exposing it to light... why is it fraught? What am I missing? If you already have a less than perfectly clean and level surface I think a peel and sick solution would be a disaster. What color are the pebbles? Check with landlord, but a dark grout with a good quality sealer might be an appealing option?

After searching for countertop fillers I conclude that there is no in-home method of filling the gazillions of shallow voids in an aggregate-based countertop while still maintaining an attractive surface. Spreading clear epoxy filler over the pores would be fraught with challenges. Foremost, it would be impossible to produce the dead-level, factory gloss finish of an original countertop. Replacing the countertops would be more straight-forward - not an option for a renter.
I hadn't thought of using an adhesive film to provide a removable food preparation surface that could be kept clean.
Yes, by all means, keep the landlord in the loop and get their permission before undertaking any "improvements".

To answer the question: So long as the surface is solid, not crumbling, you can do this with epoxy resin.  Look on youtube, there's thousands of examples.  As noted in the comments, ensure you buy a food-safe product and get the owner's permission.
Given it's a rental you may also consider a peel-and-stick cover.   It's like wallpaper for counters.  It's very cheap, very easy, and you can remove it if the landlord doesn't like it.

Pick one that's safe for food contact.

And as said in the other comments, get the owner's approval first.
